# How to store whole row from dataframe in a new dataframe when certain condition is met

Tags: python, dataframe, websocket, binance-api-client

I am streaming binance futures websocket stream for four pairs at the moment,I converted json stream into dataframe which doesn't look clean. There were other ways to print results which I searched online  but I could not make them work. Looking at the data being streamed , I want to copy/store a row if last column is "true" for that for a pair into a new dataframe. I have 4 pairs so 4 dataframes , one for each one .

And one more thing I want to stream all future pairs .How should I approach to for that goal. adding all streams in same URL "wss://fstream.binance.com"??

````
SOCKET= "wss://fstream.binance.com/stream?streams=bnbusdt_perpetual@continuousKline_1m/btcusdt_perpetual@continuousKline_1m/ethusdt_perpetual@continuousKline_1m/dashusdt_perpetual@continuousKline_1m"


def on_open(ws):
 print('opened connection')

def on_close(ws):
  print('connection closed')

def on_message(ws,message):
  json_message = json.loads(message)
  pd.DataFrame=pd.json_normalize(json_message)
  newdata=pd.DataFrame
  #print((newdata))
  df = pd.DataFrame.drop(pd.DataFrame.columns[[0,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,14,15,17,18,19,20]], axis=1)
  print(df)```

This gives me something like this (timestamp,pair,open,close,high,low,candle-closed/open)


opened connection
   
          data.E  data.ps data.k.o data.k.c data.k.h data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418469503  BNBUSDT  421.660  421.590  421.670  421.530     False
          data.E  data.ps data.k.o data.k.c data.k.h data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418469683  ETHUSDT  3192.50  3192.04  3192.50  3191.01     False
          data.E  data.ps  data.k.o  data.k.c  data.k.h  data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418469730  BTCUSDT  44044.00  44022.74  44049.69  44015.01     False
          data.E  data.ps  data.k.o  data.k.c  data.k.h  data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418469993  BTCUSDT  44044.00  44022.04  44049.69  44015.01     False
          data.E  data.ps data.k.o data.k.c data.k.h data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418470045  BNBUSDT  421.660  421.580  421.670  421.530     False
          data.E  data.ps data.k.o data.k.c data.k.h data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418470067  ETHUSDT  3192.50  3192.04  3192.50  3191.01     False
          data.E   data.ps data.k.o data.k.c data.k.h data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418470138  DASHUSDT   116.24   116.16   116.24   116.14     False
          data.E  data.ps  data.k.o  data.k.c  data.k.h  data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418470260  BTCUSDT  44044.00  44031.94  44049.69  44015.01     False
          data.E  data.ps data.k.o data.k.c data.k.h data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418470428  ETHUSDT  3192.50  3192.95  3192.95  3191.01     False
          data.E  data.ps  data.k.o  data.k.c  data.k.h  data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418470630  BTCUSDT  44044.00  44032.39  44049.69  44015.01     False
          data.E  data.ps data.k.o data.k.c data.k.h data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418470721  ETHUSDT  3192.50  3193.28  3193.51  3191.01     False
          data.E  data.ps  data.k.o  data.k.c  data.k.h  data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418470931  BTCUSDT  44044.00  44032.40  44049.69  44015.01     False
          data.E  data.ps data.k.o data.k.c data.k.h data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418471118  ETHUSDT  3192.50  3193.28  3193.51  3191.01     False
          data.E  data.ps  data.k.o  data.k.c  data.k.h  data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418471229  BTCUSDT  44044.00  44032.39  44049.69  44015.01     False
          data.E   data.ps data.k.o data.k.c data.k.h data.k.l  data.k.x
0  1644418471287  DASHUSDT   116.24   116.21   116.24   116.14     False 

Now I want to copy/store a row if last column is "true" for that for a pair in a new dataframe. I have 4 pairs so 4 dataframes . 

And one more thing I want to stream all future pairs .How should I approach to for that goal. adding all streams in same URL "wss://fstream.binance.com"??
````

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

for the first problem

you can have  a list of your data frame names and loop through them

The next step is to check for your condition

and then store the row in data frame

assume this:

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
for df in df_list:
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([])
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.iloc[i,x] == True:  #x is your column
            df1 = pd.concat(df1, df.iloc[i:i+1, x]
```

here you go
you have a df for every dataframe but remember to do your thing at the end of each loop for each dataframe